# ¿Como pedir que el rol de mi bot de discord se ponga automaticamente primero en la jerarquía del servidor?

Tags: discord.js

Estoy haciendo un bot de discord con Discord js y este tiene que repartir roles según el tiempo que ha estado conectadada una persona. El problema es que aunque tenga privilegios de administrador como el rol se pone automáticamente el último de la jerarquía de roles del servidor cuando inteto dar un rol me dice que el bot no tiene permisos suficiente. Aquí una captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me salta una interrupcion por falta de permisos al intentar asignar el rol de habitual teniendo PASM. Aunque PASM tenga administrador y habitual solo algunos permisos basicos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Como tal, esto no se puede, ya que como has de saber, un usuario de Discord (incluidos los bots) solo pueden modificar la posición y las propiedades de los roles que estén por debajo de el rol más alto que poseen y si este cuenta con permisos necesarios.

Espero haber aclarado tu duda.

Comment: En su momento ya lo acabé entendiendo pero gracias igual.